# Proximal map for a convex optimization problem

Tags: convex-optimization

I have a convex optimization problem

\begin{align*}
\max_{P\, =\, (p_{ij})}   &\sum_{ij} p_{ij} \big(a_{ij}-\log(p_{ij})\big)\\
  \text{st}\quad &p_{ij}\in\mathcal{P}_{n, m} \; \text{and} \sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij} (b_i-1)  = 0 \quad \forall j\\
 \text{where,}\; &\mathcal{P}_{n, m} := \{(p_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}_+^{n \times m}:\; \sum_{j} p_{ij} = 1,\forall i\}   
\end{align*}

This problem is related to [A convex optimization problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255982/a-convex-optimization-problem). For that problem it was suggested to use proximal operator and it worked well but for this one the proximal map doesn't have a closed-form. How to go about this?

A bit of search shows that there are these generalized proximal mappings where one replaces squared Euclidean distance with other distance-like functions. The keywords here seem to be "entropic proximal mapping" and "mirror descent". Are there versions of splitting algorithms such as Douglas-Rachford for these generalized proximal operators?

Comment: Am I correct that we interpret $p_{ij} \log(p_{ij})$ to be equal to $0$ if $p_{ij} = 0$?

Comment: @littleO indeed

Comment: By the way, how large are $m$ and $n$ typically?

Comment: @littleO  usually m << n,    n could be thousands, 
m is say ~10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is my second attempt at a solution.  My initial attempt can be found below.)

Your optimization problem can be expressed as
$$
\operatorname{minimize}_{p \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}}  \quad F(p) + G(p)
$$
where
$$
F(p) = \sum_{i,j} p_{ij}(\log(p_{ij}) - a_{ij}) + I_\Omega(p)
$$
and $I_\Omega$ is the indicator function of the set
$$
\Omega = \{ p \in \mathbb R^{n \times m} \mid p_{ij} \geq 0 \, \forall \, i,j\}
$$
(so $I_\Omega$ enforces nonnegativity on $p$)
and
$G$ is the indicator function of the set
$$
S = \{ p \in \mathbb R^{n \times m} \mid
\sum_j p_{ij} = 1 \, \forall \, i \quad \text{and}\quad
\sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij}(b_i - 1) = 0 \, \forall j \}.
$$
Evaluating the prox-operator of $G$ requires projecting onto $S$, which is a linear algebra problem with a standard closed-form solution.

We do not have a closed-form expression for the prox-operator of $F$, **but** $F$ is still a very simple function (for example, it is fully separable).  Can we not evaluate the prox-operator of $F$ numerically to high precision very efficiently?

Evaluating the prox-operator of $F$ reduces to evaluating the prox-operator of the function $w:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ defined by
$$
w(x) = \begin{cases} x \log(x) & \quad \text{if } x \geq 0, \\
\infty & \quad \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
(We interpret $x \log(x) = 0$ when $x = 0$.)
To evaluate the prox-operator of $w$ at $\hat x$ (with parameter $t > 0$), we must solve
\begin{align}
\operatorname{minimize}_x & \quad x \log(x) + \frac{1}{2t} (x - \hat x)^2 \\
\text{subject to} & \quad x \geq 0.
\end{align}
If we visualize the graph of $ v(x) = x \log(x) + \frac{1}{2t} (x - \hat x)^2$, we see that $v$ is initially decreasing (as we move away from the origin, to the right) but then eventually increases to $+\infty$.  So, $v$ has a minimizer in the interval $(0,\infty)$ which can be found by setting $v'(x) = 0$.  This yields:
$$
1 + \log(x) + \frac{1}{t}(x - \hat x) = 0
\iff x + t \log(x) = \hat x - t.
$$
The function $x + t \log(x)$ is strictly increasing, and it ranges from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ as $x$ ranges from $0$ to $+\infty$.
Thus, there is a single value of $x$ for which
$x + t \log(x) = \hat x - t$.
I think this value of $x$ can be found to high accuracy with Newton's method (and I think it won't take too many iterations).  This allows us to evaluate the prox-operator of $F$ efficiently.

Alternatively (and even better), we can express the solution to 
$$
\frac{x}{t} + \log(x) = c
$$
in terms of the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{t} + \log(x) = c & \iff
\log(e^{x/t}) + \log(x) = \log(e^c) \\
&\iff x e^{x/t} = e^c \\
&\iff (x/t) e^{x/t} = \frac{e^c}{t}\\
&\iff x/t = W(e^c/t) \\
&\iff x = t W(e^c/t).
\end{align}
In Matlab, the Lambert W-function can be evaluated using `lambertw`.

Now that we have seen how to evaluate the prox-operators of both $F$ and $G$ efficiently, we are able to minimize $F(p) + G(p)$ using the Douglas-Rachford method (which solves convex problems of exactly this form).

---

Here is my initial attempt to solve the problem, which had a certain flaw (or issue, at least) which is discussed at the end.

The Chambolle-Pock algorithm solves convex optimization problems in the canonical form (or "graph form") minimize $f(x) + g(Cx)$, where the convex functions $f$ and $g$ are "simple" (meaning they have easy prox-operators) and $C$ is a matrix or a linear transformation.  The Chambolle-Pock algorithm was extended by Condat (in [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10957-012-0245-9)) to solve convex optimization problems of the form
$$
\tag{$\spadesuit$} \operatorname{minimize}_x \quad h(x) + f(x) + g(Cx)
$$
where $f,g$ and $C$ are as above and the convex function $h$ is differentiable with a Lipschitz continuous gradient.  Your problem has the form $(\spadesuit)$ where $C$ is the identity mapping and
\begin{align}
h(p) = -\sum_{ij} \, p_{ij}(a_{ij} - \log(p_{ij})) \\
\end{align}
and $f$ is the indicator function of
$$
\{ p \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}_+ \mid \sum_j p_{ij} = 1 \, \forall i \}
$$
and
$g$ is the indicator function of
$$
\{ p \in \mathbb R^{m \times n} \mid \sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij}(b_i - 1) = 0 \, \forall j \}.
$$

**NOTE:** A **problem** (or at least an issue) with this approach is that $h$ does not have a Lipschitz continuous gradient and cannot be extended to a differentiable function $\mathbb R^{n \times m}$. That might mean this approach doesn't work.

I'd be interested to see what @MichaelGrant says about this problem.